# How to add custom shortcut which pastes a fixed string into the current cursor position?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I would like to add a keyboard shortcut, which when I type 'asdf' quickly will copy paste a fixed string into the current cursor position. I tried adding a custom keyboard shortcut, but they can't be arbitrary keys. What are some other ways how I could achieve this?
Can I somehow have arbitrary custom shortcut keys?
I tried xbindkeys and xdotool but failed to shortcut a simple key:

```
# test
"xdotool type 'ls'"
F2
```

so how could I type asdf and have a fixed string copy pasted into the current cursor position and replace the just typed asdf

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a text snippet possibility, where typing a short text snippet expands to a phrase. A significant productivity booster indeed.

Your idea to do this by scripting is very valid. I run a homemade script myself based on `snippy`.

Before moving to scripting, you may want to evaluate a few options. Caveat: all of these options do not work on the Wayland display manager, and for now, no alternatives seem available. If you are running a standard Ubuntu desktop, you need to switch to an X11 session or try scripting yourself using the experimental tools that simulate keyboard activity under Wayland (`ydotool`, `wtype`).

**Espanso**: https://espanso.org/docs/get-started/
Highly recommended to try. The setup is text based. It watches what you type, and a trigger, e.g. `:asdf` will be replaced by your custom string. Some [Wayland support](https://espanso.org/docs/next/install/linux/#install-on-wayland) already made it into the application.

**Autokey**: https://github.com/autokey/autokey
Venerable Autokey once failed on me, after which I moved to a script based solution. I did not try it after that. However, it appears to be back and properly maintained again. This is extensively controlled using a GUI. It can do exactly what you want, i.e., replace text as you type an abbreviation you defined such as `asdf`.

**texpander**: https://github.com/leehblue/texpander
This is a bash script based solution, relying on `xdotool`. It uses Zenity to present a menu with text fragments you saved, which you can select and paste. You could adapt this script to use a better menuing system like `rofi` or `dmenu`, or have the script first copy and delete a text fragment you typed, to replace it with the full text.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Espanos did the trick for me, what a simple and intuitive package :) I will leave the question open a bit longer, in case somebody has a Wayland solution, since that will be a problem for me in a few months :D

Comment: It already has some Wayland support with some limitations: https://espanso.org/docs/next/install/linux/#install-on-wayland